# What aggregate should I do in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that contains data as below sample

```
{ "_id" : "...." , "team" : [ {"name" : "A", "state" : "Active"} , {"name" : "B", "state" : "Deactive", {"name" : "C", "state" : "Unknown"} }  ]},
{ "_id" : "...." , "team" : [ {"name" : "A", "state" : "Unknown"} , {"name" : "B", "state" : "Deactive", {"name" : "C", "state" : "Unknown"} }  ]},
{ "_id" : "...." , "team" : [ {"name" : "A", "state" : "Active"} , {"name" : "B", "state" : "Deactive", {"name" : "C", "state" : "Unknown"} }  ]}
```

I filter by "team.name" and want to know what is state and count each state as below sample result

```
{ "name" : "A", "Active" : 2, "Unknown" : 1},
{ "name" : "B", "Deactive" : 3},
{ "name" : "C", "Unknown" : 3"}
```

Is it possible to use only aggregate function of MongoDB without any codes?

Comment: Do you expect yes/no answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use only aggregate function of MongoDB without any
>   codes?

Yes

**TL;DR** unwind and group

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
   {$unwind:"$team"},
   {
       $group: {
           _id: "$team.name",
           "Active": {$sum: {$cond:[{$eq:["$team.state","Active"]},1,0]}},
           "Deactive": {$sum: {$cond:[{$eq:["$team.state","Deactive"]},1,0]}},
           "Unknown": {$sum: {$cond:[{$eq:["$team.state","Unknown"]},1,0]}}
       }
   },
   {$project: {_id:0, name:"$_id", Active:1, Deactive:1, Unknown:1}},
   {$sort: {name:1}}
])
```

Output for your sample:

```
 [
    { "name" : "A", "Active" : 2, "Deactive" : 0, "Unknown" : 1 },
    { "name" : "B", "Active" : 0, "Deactive" : 3, "Unknown" : 0 },
    { "name" : "C", "Active" : 0, "Deactive" : 0, "Unknown" : 3 }
 ]
```

Comment: @taohiko u r welcome. Next time please post code which you have tried - that will encourage more people to help you and you will get not only solution, but also explanation what went wrong with your approach